# Using one xml for two activities

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to use Map in activity .

[image]
Now i explain whole problem.I have an activity and in it i want to display two types of map

1. **Button Orange**  Map for any location in portion which is at top of activity
2. **Button Blue** Map draw polyline between two point in portion which is at top of activity

I have accomplished both tasks but

1. **Button 1** in the same activity bsz map of any location can be shown by extending class with activity

   ```
      public class Map_current_Location extends Activity { 
               // Google Map
               private GoogleMap googleMap;
               @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       try {
           // Loading map
           initilizeMap();

           googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
           // Showing / hiding your current location
           googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

           // Enable / Disable zooming controls
           googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

           // Enable / Disable my location button
           googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

           // Enable / Disable Compass icon
           googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

           // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
           googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

           // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
           googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

           double latitude = 31.510586;
           double longitude = 74.341245;

               // Adding a marker
               MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                       new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                       .title("Hello Maps ");


               // changing marker color

                   marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                           .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));


               googleMap.addMarker(marker);

               // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level

                   CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                   .target(new LatLng(latitude,
                           longitude)).zoom(30).build();

                   googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                           .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       initilizeMap();
   }

   /**
    * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
    * */
   private void initilizeMap() {
       if (googleMap == null) {
           googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                   R.id.map)).getMap();

           // check if map is created successfully or not
           if (googleMap == null) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. But cannot do with second button because polyline and distance can be only done by extending class with

> public class Maps extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener

Please suggest me how can i do accomplish both in one actiivty
Please tell me if can be done by sublass..

XML FOR WHOLE ACTIVITY

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Map_contact_location"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1_contact_location" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Information_contact_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Map_contact_location" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="ftggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg "
            android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1_Setting"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/call_contact"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/phone" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/distance_map"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/directions_icon" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please extend FragmentActivity  because it is also extend Activity.

Comment: when i do this my activity (class) doesnot get started.and gives me error of inflating fragment in xml

Comment: Have you tried SupportMapFragment in place of MapFragment? and extend FragmentActivity. Also make sure you have used your app's Map key and put it in AndroidManifest with your package.